# Алгоритм приведения массива в другой формат (php)

Tags: php, массивы, sendmail

Необходимо придумать алгоритм который бы из такого массива

```
 array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["forms_email"]=> "max@gmail.com, sm@yandex.ru.ru"
            ["form_name"]=> "form_compl"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["forms_email"]=> "max@gmail.com, 123@da.fwe"
            ["form_name"]=> "TESTED"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["forms_email"]=> "sm@yandex.ru"
            ["form_name"]=> "formname2"
          }
        }
```

сделал бы такой:

```
array(3) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["forms_email"]=> "max@gmail.com"
                ["form_name"]=> "form_compl, TESTED"
              }
              [1]=>
              array(2) {
                ["forms_email"]=> "123@da.fwe"
                ["form_name"]=> "TESTED"
              }
              [2]=>
              array(2) {
                ["forms_email"]=> "sm@yandex.ru"
                ["form_name"]=> "formname2, form_compl"
              }
            }
```

то есть для каждого e-mail надо указать все `["form_name"]` где есть совпадение. это делается для отправки писем, `["form_name"]` - имена файлов, из них потом сделается массив и пойдет в качестве приложения к письму, поэтому нужен именно такой вид. размерность массива может быть любой, как и количество получателей

Comment: Ваша решение где?

Comment: Почему бы не попробовать сделать вот такой выходной массив:

    <?php
        array(3) {
            ["max@gmail.com"] => "form_compl, TESTED",
            ["123@da.fwe"]    => "TESTED",
            ["sm@yandex.ru"]  => "formname2, form_compl",
        }

И ***придумать алгоритм*** самому будет несложно и работать после будет просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напомнило [вызов **Hola**](https://habrahabr.ru/company/hola/blog/270847/).
Увидеть работу можно [тут](http://ideone.com/nMZ84w).
Код (сниппет только ради спойлера, который нужно отдельно сделать):

```html
$arr = [[
  'forms_email' => 'max@gmail.com, sm@yandex.ru',
  'form_name'   => 'form_compl'
 ], [
  'forms_email' => 'max@gmail.com, 123@da.fwe',
  'form_name'   => 'TESTED'
 ], [
  'forms_email' => 'sm@yandex.ru',
  'form_name'   => 'formname2'
 ]
];
$tmp = $result = [];
 
foreach($arr as $item){
 $subj  = trim($item['form_name']); // Получаем имя для текущих мыл
 $mails = array_map(function($e){return trim($e);},explode(',', $item['forms_email'])); // Делим мыла на массив и каждый чистим trim'ом
 
 foreach($mails as $mail){
  if(isset($tmp[$mail]))
   if(array_search($subj, $tmp[$mail]) !== false)
    continue; // Если уже мыло существует и такая метка у них есть, пропускаем итерацию
 
  $tmp[$mail][] = $subj;
 }
}
 
foreach($tmp as $mail => $subj)
 $result[] = [ // Просто приводим к требуемому виду
  'forms_email' => $mail,
  'form_name'   => implode(', ', $subj)
 ];
 
unset($tmp);
 
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Можно в одну строчку всё уложить? (написанно так что не прочитаешь)

Comment: @Naumov, если есть нужда... Но лучше так не делать, писать простой и понятный код дороже пары ms выполнения.

Кто знает `PHP` вполне может это прочесть, так что учите, сударь, учите!

Comment: так это сарказм, я вам минус и влепил за то что `[]` везде где можно и нельзя, тут вообще `array_map(function($e){return trim($e);},explode(',', $item['forms_email']));` про однострочные `if`вообще молчу.

Comment: @Naumov, если Вам не понравилось - Вы имеете права поставить минус, хотя решение рабочее, наглядное и выполняет поставленные условия. Я плакать не стану. Но и кодить в стиле, который удобен Вам тоже не стану, уж извините. Надо - перепишите под себя.